# How to trigger onText event in LatinIME

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Base on [Hacker's Keyboard](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/), I want to send text from GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) to current input (textbox).

So, how can I trigger onText event on [LatinIME.java](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/browse/java/src/org/pocketworkstation/pckeyboard/LatinIME.java) to send text (through CharSequence text to current input)

```
public void onText(CharSequence text) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you would do it.  LatinIME is a specific keyboard-  Google's.  It may or may not be installed (Samsung doesn't use it).  And the input connection is something that exists only to talk to the IME because its a separate process.  Its also pretty much a 1 way interface-  you don't cause text events in the keyboard.

You're also overthinking things.  This is your app.  Just use setText() on the view.  If you want this to happen even outside your app, you couldn't do that anyway (the keyboard only communicates with a single app at a time).

Comment: I'm going to build a new softkeyboard which I can send text over internet to my keyboard and my keyboard set the text to current active input. But it seems I have no way to trigger onText method.

Comment: That seems somewhere between convoluted and dangerous.  I know I would never use a keyboard that was sending data to the internet, I'd suspect it was sending my keystrokes, including passwords.  But keyboards don't have an onText event.  When they want to send text they call getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(CharSequence)